# Is 55 minutes enough transfer time at Schiphol

Tags: transit, airports, ams, short-connections

WE are looking to book Birmingham, England (BHX) to Nairobi on 1 May. The flight BHX-AMS is 09.40 arriving AMS 11.50. The Nairobi flight leaves at 12.45, giving us 55 minutes to transfer. Is this enough, given that both legs are KLM?

Comment: If you miss the connection, and KLM look after you until the next available flight, how much of a problem is that for you?

Comment: @SpaceDog not sure about that, is there an immigration check when you're coming from the UK ?

Comment: Shilpol is big airport. Be prepared to run :)

Answer (score 4):

If KLM allowed you to book this as a single itinerary rather than two separated tickets, then you are covered. If you miss the connection, they will have to find a solution for you with another flight.

Then you need more to think if you are ready to be delayed if you miss the connection.

In theory, 55 minutes should be enough but there is no room for any sort of delay. If your flight arrives 20 minutes late in Schipol which is not uncommon there, then you will most likely miss your connection.

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience, if things go reasonably well you are likely to get to your next connection in time. Sometimes airport/KLM staff waits in front of your flight to help you get to your connecting flight.

Unfortunately, the same can't be said about your luggage. Schiphol seems to be particularly slow with handling luggage, so there is a much greater chance that your luggage will not make it to your connecting aircraft....

Answer (score 2):

I flew through Schiphol (from Kuala Lumpar) last year with 45 minutes transfer time. I managed to make the connecting flight with 20/15 minutes to go, however my bag did not make the flight. luckily, I was heading home and my bag was delivered to my house the same day.

I found transferring from one gate to another quite frustrating due to the long walk (jog). When you go to the different gate, if it is in a different concourse you will have to go through a security/ bag check again which can be time consuming if there is a large queue

Answer (score 1):

I made a connection of 55 mins OF VIE-AMS-DOH at AMS in Dec, 2015. First leg was 10 mins late, I was on last row, so last to deboard. No checked in luggage. As soon as I hit the ground, started running towards new gate. I used the priority immigration lane, then again ran. Made to boarding counter @ gate just 5 mins before they were going to close it.

Both boarding passes were issues in VIE.

Comment: You made it to the gate/boarding counter, you mean? Check-in counter would be were you drop your luggage.

Comment: @jcaron yes, will edit my answer..